# Apache htaccess redirect file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect any request for file from my old website to the same file but with different url on my new website :

```
www.oldwebsite.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/file.txt
```

->

```
www.newwebsite.com/bbb/ccc/file.txt
```

I have tried this solution on .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(aaa/bbb/ccc/)(.*)$ http://newwebsite.com/bbb/ccc/$2 [R=301,L]
```

but when I try with this url :

```
www.oldwebsite.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/file.txt
```

it redirect to :

```
http://newwebsite.com/bbb/ccc/aaa/bbb/ccc/file.txt
```

that is wrong, it should redirect to this :

```
www.newwebsite.com/bbb/ccc/file.txt
```

Can someone help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simplified rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aaa/(bbb/ccc/.*)$ http://newwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.